# Animation freezes after copying key-frames

Tags: animation

ok so i have this animation 250 keyframes, but i want to extend it to 500 keyframes, so i select all the original 250 keyframes, then i duplicate all of em, and move them to keyframe number 251, it worked, so i got 500 keyframes in total ( i want to the animation to repeat once) but then when i play the animation it will only play correctly to 250, then it freezes all the way to keyframe number 500, can someone pls tell me whats wrong or how to fix, really appreciated it ty

Comment: since you didn't show us any settings....pls provide your blend file, thx